# D3 Visualization - Updating in ngOnChanges (Angular / TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm using [this d3 bl.ocks example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795/8f34afdd6d321b71ca6b3a5904e486f3173f1111) in [my Angular project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkvyqy), though I'm trying to update the data onChanges instead of inside the buildViz function. I've mocked this in the example below by setting an interval in ngOnInit.

I'm getting an error that it can't find the node data (`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`). I'm guessing this is because the function is being called outside of buildViz function itself, though passing in the nodes and links did not seem to resolve the issue. Any thoughts?

Error is coming from this line in my restart function:

```
node = node.data(_this.nodes, function (d) { return d.id; });
```

Working Code: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8bbzw?file=app/d3-viz.component.ts)

My code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'd3-viz',
  templateUrl: './d3-viz.html'
})
export class D3Viz {

  private host;

  width: number = 750;
  height: number = 500;

  a = { id: "a" };
    b = { id: "b" };
    c = { id: "c" };

  links = [
    { source: this.a, target: this.b },
    { source: this.b, target: this.c },
    { source: this.c, target: this.a }
  ];

  nodes = [this.a, this.b, this.c];

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    this.host = d3.select(this.element.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildViz();

      d3.interval(() => {
        this.nodes.pop(); // Remove c.
        this.links.pop(); // Remove c-a.
        this.links.pop(); // Remove b-c.
        this.buildViz('update');
      }, 2000, d3.now());

      d3.interval(() => {
        this.nodes.push(this.c);
        this.links.push({ source: this.b, target: this.c });
        this.links.push({ source: this.c, target: this.a });
        this.buildViz('update');
      }, 2000, d3.now() + 1000);

  }

    buildViz(update?) {

      let svg = this.host.append('svg')
        .attr('width', this.width)
        .attr('height', this.height);
      let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);


      if(!update){

      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation<any>(this.nodes)
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
        .force("link", d3.forceLink(this.links).distance(200))
        .force("x", d3.forceX())
        .force("y", d3.forceY())
        .alphaTarget(1)
        .on("tick", ticked);

      var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")"),
        link = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".link"),
        node = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#fff").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");

    }



      var restart = () => {

        // Apply the general update pattern to the nodes.
        node = node.data(this.nodes, function (d: any) { return d.id; });
        node.exit().remove();
        node = node.enter().append("circle").attr("fill", function (d: any) { return color(d.id); }).attr("r", 8).merge(node);

        // Apply the general update pattern to the links.
        link = link.data(this.links, function (d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
        link.exit().remove();
        link = link.enter().append("line").merge(link);

        // Update and restart the simulation.
        simulation.nodes(this.nodes);
        simulation.force<any>("link").links(this.links);
        simulation.alpha(1).restart();
      }
      restart();


      function ticked() {
        node.attr("cx", function (d: any) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function (d: any) { return d.y; })

        link.attr("x1", function (d: any) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function (d: any) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function (d: any) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function (d: any) { return d.target.y; });
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnChanges` is a lifecycle hook that is triggered **when an Input changes** (input as an Angular input, with an `@Input` decorator).

I don't really know your goal there, so I can't give you a solution, but at least I can tell you why it is not working.

As for your error, you write this :

```
  d3.interval(function () {
    this.nodes.pop(); // Remove c.
    this.links.pop(); // Remove c-a.
    this.links.pop(); // Remove b-c.
    this.buildViz(this.nodes, this.links, 'update');
  }, 2000, d3.now());
```

When you use the `this` keyword in a function, it references the function, not your component. To correct that, use this instead :

```
  d3.interval(() => {
    this.nodes.pop(); // Remove c.
    this.links.pop(); // Remove c-a.
    this.links.pop(); // Remove b-c.
    this.buildViz(this.nodes, this.links, 'update');
  }, 2000, d3.now());
```

this is the **fat arrow** notation, you should check out Google for more information about that.

And for other functions, such as `function restart(nodes, links)`, you should write it `restart = (nodes, links) => {...}` if you want to keep the context of this bound to your class.

Comment: This is just an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I'm mocking that data is changing (if that makes sense)... Can you try updating [my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mytg1m) with your suggestions as when I do it I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Well I left work, I'm on phone in the subway right now ... But I can do it tomorrow if you are willing to wait ! Unless you tell me your error, I could spot it in your new code ? (if you post your error, post it as an edit to your question, and update your code too !)

Comment: Thank you so much! I can wait. I updated my question with the most recent error / information.

Comment: This time your error comes from the restart function : `node = node.data(this.nodes`. Where do the second node comes from ? Is that a parameter ? If so, declare it in he parenthesis just before the fat arrow. If not, and it comes from your class, tienthen add `this` in front of it !

Comment: node is coming from `node = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#fff").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");` that is earlier in the buildViz() function. It's working fine in the bl.ocks example and even [my intial project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkvyqy), it's just when I try to update it, for some reason it sees it as undefined. I'm not sure how to resolve that as it's working fine (as you can see from my initial project) when updating the visualization from inside the buildViz() function.

Comment: Look at your restart function : your issue is a scope issue. Look closely at the line I pointed you to : you write node = node, but you define node in a condition ! Try to put a console log before your node declaration : I bet you won't see it :)

Comment: Thanks! I've seen it, I'm just not sure how to fix it hah, even if I don't declare node in a condition it's still not working.

Comment: I'll take a look at that tomorrow then !

Comment: @WilliamHampshire Your blitz is completely bugged, I can't seem to even edit it. The dev tools state that you are giving wrong values to your SVG attributes, does that mean you corrected all of your previous issues ?

Comment: Since you had mentioned `node` being in a condition, I removed the `update` condition. It seems to be a problem with the way I'm trying to update the visualization after it's been built. I'm stuck.

Comment: You don't need to remove your conditions or anything like that :D simply read your errors, find out where they come from (the trace is always pretty explicit on the errors), and correct them ! By lloking at your code at a glimpse, I saw that you created the node variable only when your `update` parameter wasn't set. Just create some business rules, and follow them, and you should be good to go !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166536/discussion-between-william-hampshire-and-trichetriche).

Comment: @WilliamHampshire so I managed to **[split your project into functions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eq22ns?file=app/d3-viz.component.ts)** that you can call with parameters. The issue now is that buttons aren't place on the SVG, they stay on the same spot. Since I don't know D3JS, I'm giving you this, and you will probably figure out how to place the buttons faster than I will. Anyway, I keep looking, and I will keep you updated !